# Advice to choose best web sharing GIS DATA with authorization information level

Tags: web-mapping

I need a application which allow web sharing (only reading) some GPS point on the satellite's map of my country. This solution will also permit to manage users. There will be different users to read GPS map and I want to manage the level of authorization to see information of each point.

e.g: when a administrator update the map with GPS coordinates of point A with some information to represent a location where somebody is on a business trip. I would have wanted that my boss have permission to see all information of the business trip, but that my office colleague just have the authorization to see the name of the man who is doing the business trip.

Comment: What have you researched? Do you have a budget? (for webservers, databases etc.). Does it need to be available on mobile devices?